# Custom CSS with Headway Theme

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

I'm new to building websites.

I'm currently using Headway drag and drop Wordpress builder.

I've added [Testimonial Widget by Aihrus](http://wordpress.org/plugins/testimonials-widget/) plugin for testimonials, and I've added it to a widget box.

Problem is that I want to add custom CSS to it that I've seen on [this site](http://www.siteart.co.uk/pretty-css-testimonials) that is built for it, but the Headway theme doesn't allow you to go in and edit the theme. I've tried adding it to the block inside of the theme but it didn't work. I ended up going into the plugin and adding it to the CSS of the plugin, and it now half works.

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

My site is rainorshinedogwalking.com

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your live CSS here:

http://docs.headwaythemes.com/customer/portal/articles/1067360-editing-css-directly

What you type gets minified and added to your site's dynamic CSS file on page load.

Comment: Thanks, I tried adding the custom code from the site. I named the widget block "testimonials". I then pasted the CSS code into the block's Live CSS, but nothing happened. I don't understand why

Comment: This link is no longer valid. I am looking to add my own CSS after all the Headway CSS, rather than tweak their CSS, use their style.css or their integrated "Easy to use" live editor.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to is go through design editor click on the element you want to edit then right click. A pop up box should come up and it say edit element choose that then you will see  something like that click it and add our own css